# Resources to accessing a S7 Profinet PLC (1212C) from Java

Tags: java, plc

I have a relatively special question here. At least I think it's special as Google didn't seem to be able to provide me with the information I was looking for.

I have recently purchased a S7 Starter Kit, containing a S7 1212C PLC. It's all setup and running.

What I would like to do, is to write a Java Program (without native libraries) that communicates with that controller. I know there are the S7 Java Beans, but these seem to work only with the 200/300/400 Sieries. Are there any (open-source) implementations of Java protocol-stacks, that allow to access such a PLC from Java? If not, I would be really glad to get some pointers to some specifications that would allow me to implement a rudimentary stack myself (It seems the Web is filled with high-level information, but there seems to be very little low-level stuff around :-()

Help greatly appreciated,
    Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to close this. There is no pure Java way to actually use ProfinetIO the problem is that initiating the Communication is not an issue and polling values is also possible, but in order to initiate a normal Profinet IO communication I would have to access the IP stack below TCP and UDP which Java does not allow. Unfortunately the "real time" state information sent by the plc is sent using an IP frame type Java does not support.

Answer (score 3):

There is a beta tester only Java version of **[libnodave](http://libnodave.sourceforge.net/)**, but I don't know if 1212 is supported.

Comment: Yeah ... I allready contacted the guy. Hope to recieve an answer soon. Currently, as far as I could find out the protocol is based upon ISO over TCP (RFC1006) and I could find an implementation of this in the Apache Mina Project. Besides that I allready ordered a book with description of the ProfiNet Protokol ... hopefully it will arrive soon. Also I have a requirement to be independent from any native libraries. This should be a Pure-Java solution, which eliminates quite a lot of the mostly commercial and expensive solutions.

Comment: Ok ... well now I gained some more information. Well it seems that Libnodave accesses the PLC using Profinet CBA. The guys from profinet suggested to have a look at Profinet IO, which is UDP based. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be one example of a programm talking Profinet IO available (no matter the language).

Comment: Yeah ... in the meanwhile I allredy found that out too. Seems there ist not a single example using Profinet IO (UDP). Think I might have to purchase the full spec.

Answer (score 1):

The S7-1200 and S7-1500 series are capable of communicating via ModbusTCP (see https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/8869/using-an-s7-1200-plc-as-a-modbus-tcp-slave).

There's a Java library to communicate via ModbusTCP: http://jamod.sourceforge.net (haven't tried it yet).

Maybe this combination will work for you.

Comment: In fact old S7-300 and S7-400 where also able to communicate via ModbusTCP via the CPU port or an added CP card, however it was necessary to acquire a separate license to use this functionality, as it was not included in the default functions library (in the S7-1200 and S7-1500 series happily an improved version of this library is now included by default).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is helpful for you, but we have a java library (LGPL 3.0) which talks natively via TCP/IP with S7 devices.

have a look at http://openscada.org

The code itself can be found at http://git.openscada.org/?p=org.openscada.atlantis.git;a=tree;f=org.openscada.da.server.dave;hb=HEAD

Comment: Thanks for that ... I'll have a look into it. I actually manaually implemented part of the Profinet IO protocol, but for the actual data interchange I would have to go below TCP on the protocol stack, which is not possible in Java therefore I abandoned it. Think this Profinet CBA implementation would suffice for what I want to use it for and I could see that it utilizes a lot of the Tools I allreasy use as a developer (JCIFS, JInterop, ...) Thanks for that pointer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Moka7](http://snap7.sourceforge.net/moka7.html): it's an implementation of the S7 protocol in Java.